# How do I refer to a second text element in a second svg

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3 and js and I can't figure out how to refer to a second text element (not sure if element is the correct term) in a second svg element.

I have two svg elements, one is a network diagram (with nodes and links) and one is a scatterplot (with lat/long locations).  The nodes in the network diagram and the rectangles in the scatterplot matrix both have text elements associated with them in svg groups.  I need to distinguish between the two text elements in my mouseover events, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Different source data are used for each: graph.nodes for the network diagram, graph.locs for the scatterplot.  Both have the class "location", which is used to make the connection between the two during mouseover.  The svgs are called "svg" and "svg2", but the groups are both called "g", and the text elements are both called "text".

I have posted an example as a jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/JVAdams/LXFMx/.  For example, when I mouseover a node in the network diagram (Sally), I would like the text of the corresponding location in the scatterplot map to be enlarged (TorontoON).  Here is a snippet of code

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.name + " " + d.location; })
    .call(force.drag)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 6); 
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke", "orange"); 
        d3.select(this).select("text").style("font", "20px sans-serif");
        d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke-width", 6);
        d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke", "orange");
    // this line doesn't work
    d3.selectAll("text." + d.location).style("font", "20px sans-serif");
        d3.selectAll("tr." + d.name).style("background-color", "orange");
        })
    .on("mouseout",  function(d) { 
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke-width", 1.5); 
        d3.select(this).select("circle").style("stroke", "gray"); 
        d3.select(this).select("text").style("font", "12px sans-serif");
        d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke-width", 1.5);
        d3.selectAll("rect." + d.location).style("stroke", "black");
        d3.selectAll("text." + d.location).style("font", "12px sans-serif");
        d3.selectAll("tr." + d.name).style("background-color", "white");
        });
```

In place of the line that doesn't do what I want, I have tried a number of ways to properly refer to the text element of the scatterplot, without success:

```
    d3.selectAll("mapit.text." + d.location).style("font", "20px sans-serif");
    d3.selectAll("g.text." + d.location).style("font", "20px sans-serif");
    d3.selectAll("svg2.text." + d.location).style("font", "20px sans-serif");
    d3.selectAll("svg2.g.text." + d.location).style("font", "20px sans-serif");
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not added a class to the `text` elements under the `mapit` SVG.

```
mapit.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.long); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.lat) -5; })
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .text(function(d) { return d.location; })
  .attr("class", function(d) { return d.location ;});   // <<< Add this line
```

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  And with that fixed, I was able to fix the other parts as well.  Here's the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVAdams/LXFMx/1/).